# Python AsyncHTMLSession with lambda function with variable not work

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests-html

Code below get `4,4,4,4,4`

expected `0,1,2,3,4`

It works with functools.partial but not lambda, how to fix it?

```py
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()


async def download(index):
    print(index) 


def main():
    lst = []
    for index in range(5):
        lst.append(lambda: download(index))

    asession.run(*lst)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass index to your lambda like this: `lambda index=index: download(index)`

```py
def main():
    lst = []
    for index in range(5):
        lst.append(lambda: download(index))
    
    # Here when you run your lambda the index variable is in
    # the main function scope, so the value is 4 for all the lambda
    # because the loop is ended.
    asession.run(*lst)
```

```py
def main():
    lst = []
    for index in range(5):
        lst.append(lambda foo=index: download(foo))
    
    # Here a new variable foo is created in the scope of the lambda
    # with the value of index for each iteration of the loop
    asession.run(*lst)
```

For more information, it is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) !